# Inherit proxy_set_header when using it in location block

Tags: nginx

I am trying to set up a bunch of virtual hosts on Nginx and I want to set some headers before passing the request upstream. I have some headers that I always want to set and then I have some headers that I want to set for selected location blocks.

Unfortunately, it *seems* that Nginx does not allow the `proxy_set_header` directive on multiple levels and as a result, it just clears any headers set in the http block.

Nginx documentation states the following on `proxy_set_header`:

> Allows redefining or appending fields to the request header passed to
>   the proxied server. The value can contain text, variables, and their
>   combinations. **These directives are inherited from the previous level
>   if and only if there are no proxy_set_header directives defined on the
>   current level**.

So the question is... either Nginx has a disappointing limitation or I am thinking about this problem in the wrong way.

Any ideas on an idiomatic solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Create a file to include in each block that sets the headers you want.
(So a common inc-http-headers.conf) that you include in the http block and all of the location blocks that need the common headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/) or at least its [`headers-more-nginx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module), you can do this with the [`more_set_input_headers`](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_set_input_headers) directive.

For example, the following will do what you expect:

```
http {
    # ...
    more_set_input_headers "Foo: 1";
    server {
        # ...
        more_set_input_headers "Bar: 2";
        location / {
            more_set_input_headers "Qux: 3";
            proxy_pass http://some-server;
            # request to some-server has Foo: 1, Bar: 2, and Qux: 3
        }
    }
}
```

There are some quirks to this approach however. You cannot alter the `Connection` or `Host` headers this way and you may need to be careful when nginx's own caching is enabled and you're modifying cache-related headers. If you aren't concerned with cache-related headers, then the biggest places these limitations crop up are: 1) getting WebSockets to work and 2) with upstreams that use the `Host` header in a nontrivial way.

Consequentially, a good rule of thumb I've found is to use `proxy_set_header` for `Connection` and `Host` and `more_set_input_headers` for everything else.

Comment: I don't think `Host` is listed on the limitations of https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#limitations

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh It's not listed, but it probably should be. It doesn't seem to be possible to override the `Host` header for a proxied request using `more_set_input_headers` at all. I've tried setting it to `$host`, `$http_host`, and `dummy` and it always looks instead like the value of `$proxy_host` on the receiving end. I think this is because nginx *always* sets `Host` and `Connection` and does so *after* the headers_more module hook runs.

Comment: I found a related GitHub issue regarding the `Host` header at https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module/issues/129

Comment: Thanks for sending the link, ya actually I'm running into the same issues with the host as well.